Node.js Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\\Projects\\Bookmarklets\\images\\easyweb-32.png
I have a question.
In the main code block, I am calling createRoundedCorners(fileName1, fileName2) function that takes an existing fileName1 image and from it creates fileName2 image with rounded corners. Then, I am calling imageToBase64(filePath) to read this image file and create base64 string from it. But, for some reason, on the first run, imageToBase64(filePath) function throw an exception
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\\Projects\\Bookmarklets\\images\\easyweb-32.png
I know the file is created before imageToBase64(filePath) function is called.
So, on the second run, it doesn't throw an error anymore.
Why is this happening and how to solve the issue? Thank you.
Main code block:
createRoundedCorners(fileName1, fileName2);

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'images', fileName2);

const base64string = imageToBase64(filePath);

imageToBase64(filePath) function:
// Function to convert an image file to a Base64 string
function imageToBase64(filePath) {
  try {
    // Read the image file synchronously
    const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(filePath);

    // Convert the file buffer to a Base64 string
    const base64String = imageBuffer.toString('base64');

    return base64String;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error reading file:', error.message); // Throws an exception on the first run here
  }
}


Problem
The error occurs because the imageToBase64() function attempts to read the file before it has been fully created by createRoundedCorners(). This happens due to Node.js's asynchronous nature, where subsequent code execution doesn't wait for asynchronous operations to complete unless explicitly managed.

Solution
To resolve the issue, ensure that imageToBase64() is called only after createRoundedCorners() has completed the file creation. This can be achieved by:

Returning a Promise in createRoundedCorners(): This ensures the function resolves only after the file is fully created.
Using Asynchronous fs.promises.readFile: This avoids blocking the event loop when reading the file.

Here’s the updated code:

Updated Code
1. Modify createRoundedCorners()
Make createRoundedCorners() an asynchronous function that resolves when the file is created:
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function createRoundedCorners(fileName1, fileName2) {
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'images', fileName2);

  // Simulate file creation logic (replace with actual implementation)
  await fs.promises.writeFile(filePath, 'dummy image content');
}

2. Asynchronous imageToBase64()
Use fs.promises.readFile for reading files asynchronously without blocking:
async function imageToBase64(filePath) {
  try {
    const imageBuffer = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath);
    return imageBuffer.toString('base64');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error reading file:', error.message);
    throw error;
  }
}

3. Main Code Block
Control execution flow using async/await to ensure proper sequencing:
(async () => {
  try {
    const fileName1 = 'input.png'; // Example input file
    const fileName2 = 'easyweb-32.png'; // Output file

    // Create the file and wait for it to complete
    await createRoundedCorners(fileName1, fileName2);

    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'images', fileName2);

    // Convert the created image to Base64
    const base64string = await imageToBase64(filePath);
    console.log('Base64 String:', base64string);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
  }
})();


Many thanks! This works !!
